# How to add a new service on top of an existing path

Tags: feathersjs

I'm trying to build a service whose path I wanted to extend from an existing path. Here's my scenario. I have one service called `instances` which has, among others, the path `/instances/<id>/` which can retrieve information about an instance. I want to add a new service for fetching `screenshot` of the instance. And I wanted it to be on the path: `/instances/<id>/screenshot`. But as you know on feathersjs, creating a new service registers it on its own path, in this case `/screenshot`.

Is it possible to do what I intended ? Having the new service on top of the existing? I might be using the wrong terms here, but I need the `screenshot` endpoint to access the `<id>` of the `instances` endpoint.

I tried creating the service, but it gets registered on its own path, which means if I have to access the `instance id`, I would probably pass it as a query param. My requirement was to have the `instance id` passed on the path.

Answer (score 0):

You can do what you are looking for by registering the service on a path of `instances/:instanceId/screenshot`. The instance id will then be available in [params.route](https://feathersjs.com/api/koa.html#params-route) as `params.route.instanceId`.